# Not all textviews move when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

My app looks like this:

[image: keyboard hidden]

As you can see, there are a few textviews for the measurements, below that a textview for some info (where it says bluetooth disconnected...) and last an edittext field to post something. When you press to write something, the keyboard shows up, but ONLY the last textview moves and overlaps the measurements, like this:

[image: keyboard on]

I don't really care if the screen resizes or pan, and I have tried all attributes in manifest file (nothing, adjustResize, adjustPan) with no success, the same thing happens...

I have also tried to delete all these textviews with the icons and leave just one simple textview. The same thing: **ONLY the last textview moves**...

The layout is build with fragments to swipe the views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the specific fragment that we have the problem has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/pm25resized"
            android:text="PM 2.5μm" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="μg/m3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/pm10resized"
            android:text="PM 10μm" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="μg/m3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/humidityresized"
            android:text="Humidity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send3"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="%" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/temperatureresized"
            android:text="Temperature" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/send4"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="°C" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send512" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas???

Comment: try this in manifest may it works,
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Comment: No it does not work. No other idea, anyone?